# OpenCV in web applications

Tags: java, web-applications, opencv

I want to know , how I can use OpenCV library in web apps.I am creating a web app which needs to do some image processing.I am thinking of using OpenCV for image processing,but when googling I only get , how to install OpenCV on windows/linux etc.I want to use it on a web server so the end user doesn't have to do any setup to use the websites.

I am using java to create my web app and to deploy it on google app engine.I can use alternatives to google app engine,in case using OpenCV is not available on it.

Please tell me how to use OpenCV in java web apps.Link to some resource will be very useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Web application doing image processing inside of web server is not a well-designed system. You should have a separate image processing engine from web server.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin Please, can you elaborate your comment? How to set up a "separate image processing engine" and how  to use it with a web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processing will be server side, you just send the results to the client, you basically just need an interface to OpenCV, something like [javacv](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/)

Comment: javacv requires me to install opencv,which can't be done on google app engine.is there any cloud platform which allows to install opencv for free?Amazon ec2 requires international credit  card :(

Comment: @vishesh EC2 would have been the best choice. You're stuck... Can't you use your own server at home with dyndns ?

Comment: I don't exactly remember, but does Rackspace offer a free tier for startups?